# Is there a way to use Chrome in a webview in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, webrtc, kurento, videochat

I need to build video chat application with the option to record the video call. I think that most appropriate would be to use WebRTC, specifically Kurento. However, Safari does not support WebRTC at this moment, and the iOS client SDK's don't offer the ability to record the video. This is supported for a javascript client:

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-one2one-adv.html

So I was thinking to open a chrome browser inside my app just for the webRTC functionality. I read about Blink WebKit but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

P.S. Any other proposed solutions for the video call + recording features on an iOS app are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, you can't use Chrome on IOS for webRTC. Apple for some reason don't like peer to peer technologies, and while they are rumoured to be working on it, there is no announcement yet.

There is this...

> **cordova-plugin-iosrtc**
>
> Cordova iOS plugin exposing the full WebRTC W3C JavaScript APIs.
>
> Public Google Group (mailing list) for questions and discussions about
>   cordova-plugin-iosrtc. Bug Tracker for reporting issues and requesting
>   new features (please don't use the bug tracker for questions or
>   problems, use the mailing list instead). NPM package. Yet another
>   WebRTC SDK for iOS?
>
> Absolutely not. This plugin exposes the WebRTC W3C API for Cordova iOS
>   apps (you know there is no WebRTC in iOS, right?), which means no need
>   to learn "yet another WebRTC API" and no need to use a specific
>   service/product/provider.

https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

*Warning: Some assembly required*

See this article for more details on the pitfalls:

http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/